# put together two selects in one column in sql (apex)

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

i have 3 tables: reservation (with foreign key showing_id_showing), showing (with column "date" and foreign key film_id_film) and film (with column "title").
i need to show date together with film title in one column.

separately it will look like this, but i don't know how to put it together.

```
(SELECT date FROM showing WHERE id_showing=showing_id_showing) "Date",
(SELECT title FROM film WHERE id_film=film_id_film) "Title",
```

Comment: What's the end goal here? Executing a query where you have 2 values concatenated into one column? And these values are from different tables? And you can't figure out how to join your tables? If you have an actual datamodel, include it in your question so noone has to make guesses on how to join the data together.

Answer (score 0):

To get the result set from multiple tables in SQL Server you can you SQL JOIN command. Below is similar example using INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT S.Date,T.Title FROM Showing S 
Inner Join Title 
on T.ID_Film = T.Film_ID_Film 
Where S.ID_Showing=S.Showing_ID_Showing
```

The actual solution may vary as per your table schema definition.

Comment: i still can't figure it out. excerpt of my table schema: reservation(id_reservation (PK), seans_id_seans (FK)), showings(id_showings (PK), date, film_id_film (FK)), film(id_film, title)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT film.title || ' @ ' || showing.date AS title_and_date
  FROM reservation
INNER JOIN showing
ON showing.id_showing = reservation.showing_id_showing
INNER JOIN film
ON film.id_film = reservation.film_id_film
WHERE reservation.id_reservation = :THE_RESERVATION_I_WANT_TO_SHOW
```

This is assuming you wanted to concatenate to get "one column".

Also assuming you wanted to show the one reservation. Otherwise just drop the last line with the WHERE